# How to made width and height of an element to be more flexible?

Tags: css

I have an element that needs to be wrapped. I would like to know if there are any more effective way to create this wrapper than set height and width because I have to change it so many times to get what I want.

```css
.search{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px; 
    width:20px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of different times you've had to set its size? You could use a percent as a width, a max and min width with percent, flex, css variables, etc. There's a lot of options, but we can't tell which would be the best from the information provided.

Comment: Can you a share jsfiddle with us? Explaining what you're trying to accomplish. I would advise to give a certain height to the parent element & set `.search`'s height to a percentage

Comment: height and width are equals, do you try to make a square than can get bigger and smaller ?

Comment: @GammaGames I'm sorry. https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-herschel-ugsrg. This is my sandbox link. I want to made the "Search" button to be like in the img, but I have to set the height and width so many time

Answer (score 0):

you could get rid of the width and use

```
.search{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: No, it's seem to be doesn't fix at all